# Align bootstrap div rows side by side even on window resize

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to force my divs to be on the same line, even  when the screen is resized to a smaller one. I made the  table width `20%` just to  show, that the buttons are on a new line.  But  is there a way to force the buttons inside the divs to  be on one line, even on resizing  the window? The table should probably also have a `min-width` then, so the row won't go out of the table.

**Should look like this:**

[image]

**But looks like this:**

```html
<link
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<table style="width:20%;">
  <tr>
    <td id="123">
      <div class='row ml-1'>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have a `col-xs-6` on your `div` + some margin classes. So he wont ever fit. Why dont you just set `col`  instead ?

Comment: Why having a `width:20%` on your table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you even using the row and col, you can simply use flex on the div to achieve this

```html
<link
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<table style="width:20%; ">
  <tr>
    <td id="123">
      <div class='ml-1 d-flex'>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: probably because on phone, it would be impossible to read ?

Comment: Your question says to have all these on same line even on small screens so it would be good to have scrollable list. these are scrollable horizontally

Comment: that's the reason I have added extra buttons to simulate what happens if the list have more buttons than screen width. you can check the results in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I start to remove the `width:20%;` on your table. Then I set `.container` your `tr` and add a `.col-sm-auto` to make sure that column will respect this line.

After I will recommand you to no use margin (right/left) with column and use padding instead because will create a break point...

```html
<link
  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<table style="">
  <tr>
    <td class="container" id="123">
      <div class='row ml-1'>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-auto mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-auto mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-auto mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-auto mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 col-sm-auto mr-1 mb-3'>
          <button onclick='toggleHideShowTC(this.id)' id='33' title='Passed' class='btn btn-success rounded text-light font-weight-bold h6 p-1 d-inline-block'>
              2331 &#10003;
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```